# rake yard VS yardoc

Tags: ruby, yard, yardoc

I'm getting different results when I run `yardoc` vs when I run `rake yard`

```
$ yardoc
Files:         123
Modules:         4 (    0 undocumented)
Classes:       120 (    0 undocumented)
Constants:      11 (    0 undocumented)
Attributes:     16 (    0 undocumented)
Methods:       440 (    0 undocumented)
 100.00% documented

$ rake yard
Files:         123
Modules:         4 (    0 undocumented)
Classes:       120 (    0 undocumented)
Constants:      11 (    0 undocumented)
Attributes:     16 (    0 undocumented)
Methods:       544 (    2 undocumented)
 99.71% documented
```

I'm not sure where the extra 104 methods are coming from, or which 2 of them aren't documented yet. Is it coming from my gems?

I've tried looking for an answer but haven't found anything. Can somebody point me in the right direction to explain this discrepancy, or whether it really matters?

I've also tried running `$ yard --list-nodoc` but it gives me similar results to `$ yardoc`; which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

The YARD [README](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/main/README.md) should have the info you need. In particular, the `yarddoc` [command](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/main/README.md#generating-documentation) "will assume your files are located in the `lib/` directory", but this behavior can be customized in a `.yardopts` [file](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/CLI/Yardoc).

Similarly, `rake yard` by default looks for files matching `lib/**/*.rb`, but this can be customized in the `Rakefile`, e.g.:

```
require 'yard'

YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new do |t|
  t.files   = ['lib/**/*.rb', OTHER_PATHS]
end
```

TL;DR: check the project's `.yardopts` and `Rakefile` files.